# Unable to receive events in Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android

I have registered a Broadcast receiver in the MainActivity by using the following code:

```
OrientationBroadcastReceiver orientationBR = new OrientationBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter orientationIF = new IntentFilter(
                    Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);
MainActivity.this.getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(orientationBR, orientationIF);
```

When the application is running, the broadcast events do get received by my broadcast listener. But when I close my app and open another app, the orientation change events are not broadcasted to my receiver. Could someone throw some light on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A receiver registered programatically only receives broadcast when app is open..
In order to receive broadcast when your app is closed, you need to register this receiver in manifest file.

Comment: Then what if I want to allow user to unregister/register the receiver by click of a button in my app? How would I do that with manifest file?

Comment: That cannot be done.. In that case you will have to do both... Register in manifest as well as registering it programatically..Or you can do it in a service.